# Ubuntu upgrade 12.04 the disk drive for / is not ready or not present

Tags: upgrade, mount, dpkg, dependencies

When upgrading Ubuntu to 12.04, I get the message

```
the disk drive for / is not ready or not present.
```

I tried

```
mount -n -o remount,rw /` and `dpkg --configure -a
```

which gives me this error:

```
parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 11274 package 'xmind'
blank line in value of field 'Description'
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but this gives me

```
Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
E: unable to correct dependencies
```

Which is where I'm lost. Any help appreciated.